# How to set value of textarea in different HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am building a chrome/firefox web extension. When the user clicks the button in the extension's popup, the extension's UI changes.

Here's a visual example:

Before pressing one of three buttons:

[image: Pre_Button_Press]

After pressing one of three buttons:

[image: Post_Button_Press]

As you can see from the screenshot, after pressing the button, a `textarea` is created.

Here is the code that does that (this function is called when one of the three original buttons is pressed):

```
function createSummaryBox(summary) {
    console.log("Setting textarea content to: " + summary)
    window.location.href = "../summary_page/summary_page.html";
    document.getElementById('summary-field').value = summary;
}
```

However, even when this function is called, the content inside of the `textarea` does not change.

Instead, I get the following error:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Here is the code for "summary_page.html":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../common/common_styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="summary_page.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class = container>
        <textarea class="summary-field" type="text" disabled="disabled" id = "summary-field"></textarea>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn">Back</button>
            <button class="btn">Copy</button>
            <button class="btn">Enlarge</button>
            <script src="summary_page.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, the sole content of "summary_page.js" is `console.log("Summary Page Loaded);`, which is printed out to the console.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Once you change non-hash part of `location`, a new page starts loading immediately, the old one is destroyed, including the code after `location`, then the new page runs its scripts, etc. The modern approach is to use hash/history navigation instead.

Comment: How would I use hash/history navigation?

Comment: Well, there are many examples/tutorials. Alternatively you can save the value in chrome.storage.local or sessionStorage.

Comment: Would you recommend one method over the other?