# How to fix TypeError: browser.storage is undefined in chrome/firefox web extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

Note - this question is based off of this question (although it's not necessary to read the previous question): [How to set value of textarea in different HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742919/how-to-set-value-of-textarea-in-different-html-file)

I have the following code, which is supposed to add a value into the local storage of firefox/chrome and then change the extension's UI (the code will differ slightly based upon which browser is being used, as of now, the code is for a extension in firefox):

```
function createSummaryBox(summary) {
    console.log("Setting textarea content to: " + summary);
    const currentSummary = {
        currentSummary: summary
    }
    browser.storage.local.set(currentSummary);
    window.location.href = '../summary_page/summary_page.html';
}
```

However, I get the following error whenever this function is called:

> ReferenceError: browser.storage is not defined

How can I fix this error? I read through the MDN documentation on this method, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: `To use this API you need to include the "storage" permission in your manifest.json file.` - did you do that?

Comment: Oh whoops, I thought the permission was only necessary if you were trying to have over 5mb of local storage.

Comment: You must've read some different documentation on MDN then, because I see no reference to "5mb" anywhere in the [storage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage)

Comment: The 5MB limit you are talking about is the limit to the data held in `chrome.storage.local`, which you can also remove by adding the `"unlimitedStorage"` permission. Also, the documentation you read is probably https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46081284/firefox-webextention-api-typeerror-browser-browseraction-is-undefined/46081656

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)

Answer (score 16):

as comments suggest, you need to declare permission.
In `manifest.json` add:

```
"permissions": [
    "storage"
],
```

or add it to any existing permissions:

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "storage"
],
```

[Mozilla doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Example)
[Chrome doc page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#manifest)

There are some posts saying the Storage API can't be used in Content scripts.
It's not true, Storage API can be used in any context of an extension. Content script, background script even extension service worker.

What we discuss here is Extension Storage APIs, or in WebExtension's documentation referred to as just Storage APIs.
Object is browser.storage or chrome.storage.

There is also Web Storage APIs, which is using object window.localStorage.
These two gets confused quite often.
window.localStorage can still be used on Content Scripts, but it's using the site's space there, while the rest of the extension, background script, options, are in extension space. On different domain, e.g. moz-extension://16d036aa-383d-4819-b50d-eec09739ff02/ vs https://example.com/

Comment: Can't be used in `background` script too?

Comment: It can. I wrote "can be used in content script" which was a reaction to some posts claiming it can't be used in Content scripts. I edited the response now, as it was indeed confusing.